# How to align the data in CSV file and store the proper result of the data using PANDAS?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am working with pandas in Jupyter Notebook, When I tried to read a csv file using pandas it successfully reads the file. But, when I tried to display the data in the csv file  using **data.head()** it doesn't show the proper results and I want to align the data for the particular column **['education']** in the csv.
[Error message it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw31f.png)
I need to display data in the column education field.Can ayone please help me to sort it out?

Comment: try sep=';' in your read_csv command.

Comment: Awesome sir, Thanks a lot. Actually I tried sep = '\t'.It didn't work but now it works perfectly. Thanks a ton sir.

Comment: Sorry sir, Actually I am very new user to ML. To clarify my doubts I was started this account but definitely i didn't and i won't ask questions with zero surfing.

Comment: Sir if you don't mind, Could you clarify my another doubt? Actually when I am trying to display columns from the csv it shows like[" 'age' ", " 'bp' ", " ' rsv' " and so on] but I want to display like [ "age" , "bp" , "rsv" and so on] How can I solve this sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are using semicolon instead of commas in csv.
This is the reason .head() is also printing everything in just one column.
Mention separator (sep=';') in read_csv method which will make individual columns and your will get values under education column too. Right now education column is blank.

Comment: Sir if you don't mind, Could you clarify my another doubt? Actually when I am trying to display columns from the csv it shows like[" 'age' ", " 'bp' ", " ' rsv' " and so on] but I want to display like [ "age" , "bp" , "rsv" and so on] How can I solve this sir